# Can I load my combo box with values from an array using Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently loading information to a second & third combo box depending on the selection on my first combo box. I am loading the information from an array. It is working fine but the set of codes is really long. Is there a way to make it more neater and reduce the amount of code. One other way I thought of is to use data binding and read around. But I can't grasp how to data bind my array values to the combo box. Thanks for advice.

```
//1st combo box name - secondaryTable 
//2nd combo box name - stCombo1 
//3rd combo box name - stCombo2

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ComboBoxItem)secondaryTable.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Agents")
            {
                stCombo1.Items.Clear();
                stCombo2.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string x in tableArray)
                {
                    stCombo1.Items.Add(x);
                    stCombo2.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
            else if (((ComboBoxItem)secondaryTable.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Missions")
            {
                stCombo1.Items.Clear();
                stCombo2.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string x in attributeArray)
                {
                    stCombo1.Items.Add(x);
                    stCombo2.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stCombo1.Items.Clear();
                stCombo2.Items.Clear();
                foreach (string x in jobsArray)
                {
                    stCombo1.Items.Add(x);
                    stCombo2.Items.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To Build on Peter's answer, you can also directly bind the combobox's [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) to the array of strings you want to use. Should look something like:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (((ComboBoxItem)secondaryTable.SelectedItem).Content.ToString())
    {
        case "Agents": 
            stCombo1.ItemsSource = tableArray; 
            stCombo2.ItemsSource = tableArray; 
            break;
        case "Missions":
            stCombo1.ItemsSource = attributeArray; 
            stCombo2.ItemsSource = attributeArray; 
            break;
        default: 
            stCombo1.ItemsSource = jobsArray; 
            stCombo2.ItemsSource = jobsArray; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Assuming these are just arrays of strings, the databinding should be very simple. If it's not, you have a little bit of extra work to do.